# libzip can't close file

Tags: c++, c++11, libzip

I'm currently using libzip in a C++11 program to extract the contents of a compressed file and store them into a data structure that will also hold metadata related to the file.

I'm using the current method to explode the zip file and get the content of each file in it:

```
void explodeArchive(const string& path, vector<ZipFileModel>& files) {
    int error = 0;
    zip *zip = zip_open(path.c_str(), 0, &error);
    if (zip == nullptr) {
      throw logic_error("Could not extract content of file " + path);
    }
    const zip_int64_t n_entries = zip_get_num_entries(zip, ZIP_FL_UNCHANGED);
    for (zip_int64_t i = 0; i < n_entries; i++) {
      const char *file_name = zip_get_name(zip, i, ZIP_FL_ENC_GUESS);
      struct zip_stat st;
      zip_stat_init(&st);
      zip_stat(zip, file_name, ZIP_FL_NOCASE, &st);
      char *content = new char[st.size];
      std::cerr << file_name << std::endl;
      zip_file *file = zip_fopen(zip, file_name, ZIP_FL_NOCASE);
      const zip_int64_t did_read = zip_fread(file, content, st.size);
      if (did_read <= 0) {
        continue;
      }
      if (strlen(content) < st.size) {
        LOG(WARNING)<< "File " << file_name << " is truncated.";
      }
      if (strlen(content) > st.size) {
        content[st.size] = '\0';
      }

      ZipFileModel model;
      model.name = string(file_name);
      model.content = string(content);
      model.order = -1;
      files.push_back(model);

      zip_fclose(file);
      delete[] content;
    }
    zip_close(zip);
  }
```

My problem is that I get random segmentation faults with gdb pointing to `zip_fclose(file);`:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001001ef8a0 in zip_source_close (src=0x105001b00) at /Users/xxx/Projects/xxx/xxx/src/libzip/zip_source_close.c:48
48      (void)src->cb.l(src->src, src->ud, NULL, 0, ZIP_SOURCE_CLOSE);
```

What's the best way to debug this? As I said it happens intermittently so it's hard to pin down the exact cause.

Comment: I don't think `strlen` is being used correctly there. I could be wrong about that. However, `content[st.size] = '\0';` is definitely wrong, given that the array has only `st.size` elements.

Comment: My best recommendation is not to debug this, but to rewrite it using structures that are less prone to such bugs. Especially `std::vector<char>` instead of `new char[]`, but a RAII wrapper over `zip_file*` that throws if opening fails would also help. Even if that doesn't fix the bugs, it makes it easier to debug them.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it, although I don't think it's possible.

Comment: R.MartinhoFernandes Can you turn your first comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Oh, was that the issue? I didn't think it could be related to the close failure.

Comment: Neither did I, but commenting out that line made it go away. Also, how'd you truncate the document?

Comment: Just make the buffer bigger, I guess. the largest index is `st.size-1`. `st.size` is outside the bounds of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks! Again, turn it into an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't closing the zip_file when there's nothing to read.

First you open the file inside:

```
zip_file *file = zip_fopen(zip, file_name, ZIP_FL_NOCASE);
```

Then try to read something:

```
  const zip_int64_t did_read = zip_fread(file, content, st.size);
```

and if there's nothing to read you continue and the file is never closed.

```
  if (did_read <= 0) {
    continue;
  }
```

So, just add:

```
if (did_read <= 0) {
    zip_fclose(file);
    continue;
}
```